# In jqgrid how to maintain the state of the grid even after sorting

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Incrementing particular column in the jqgrid after the service call  ,then i am doing automatic sorting using `sortable:true,sortorder:asc,sorttype:int` .
              When i am sorting, the value in the column is not restored it is vanished and then the grid is sorted .can anybody help me in this situation ,so that i can restore my value even after sorting .

```
here is the code, 

$('#gridValue)
      .jqGrid(
           {

            datastr :parsedObj,
            datatype :'jsonstring',
            height :140,
            width :240,
            colNames : [ "Id","Name","Count" ],
            colModel : [ {
               name :'id',
               index :'id',
               width :30,
               align :'left',
               sortable :true
            }, {
               name :'name',
               index :'name',
               width :30,
               align :'left'
            }, {
               name :'count',
               index :'count',
               width :20,
               align :'left',
               sortable :true
             }],

             rowNum :20,
             sortname : 'id',
             sorttype :'int',
             scroll :true,
             viewrecords :true,
             shrinkToFit :false,
             hoverrows :true,
             cellEdit :true,
             loadonce :true,
             sortorder :'asc',

               jsonReader : {
                   root :'paramValue',
                   repeatitems :false,
                   page : function(parsedObj) {
                   return 1;
                   },
                   total : function(parsedObj) {
                   return 1;
                   },
                   records : function(parsedObj) {
                   }
                   },
               gridComplete : function() {
                   var gridTable = document
                            getElementById("gridValue");
                   var gridTableCount = gridTableCount.rows.length;
                   if (gridTableCount> 1) {
                      for (countId = 1; countId < gridTableCount; countId++) {
   document.getElementById("gridValue").rows[countId].cells[2].innerHTML = '0';                                                                   }
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                        });     
                        $("#gridValue").setGridParam({
                                sortname : 'count',
                                sortorder : 'asc'
                        }).trigger('reloadGrid');
                   }

//After service call i will be calling this function to update value in grid
function incrementingValue(){
     document.getElementById("gridValue").rows[countId].cells[2].innerHTML =1;
}
```

But after automatic sorting in the grid the value is not retained.Pls provide me a solution

Comment: Can you include the code for that particular column, including any formatters, etc? In fact, it might help to post all of your grid code, if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the id column to

{
           name :'id',
           index :'id',
           width :30,
           align :'left',
           sortable :true,
           formatter: incrementingValue
        }

then add a function after the grid code to handle the increment

```
var counter; //when calling the service you can increase your value to the counter
function incrementingValue(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    //var cellValueInt = parseInt(cellvalue); // this bring the existing cell value
    return counter=1;
    }
};
```